# Why I only have two slots on my mac when running a openmpi program

Tags: mpi, openmpi

And I run it on Linux , it can be even 200 or 1000. It really confused me. Could anyone explain that? thx!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question accordingly. Like this, it's hard to discern what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, your Mac likeky has one socket with two cores and two hyperthreads each.

By default, Open MPI can run up to 2 MPI tasks.

You have two options here

- `mpirun  --use-hwthread-cpus ...` so you can run up to 4 MPI tasks
- `mpirun --oversubscribe ...` so you can run any number of MPI tasks